# Zend: Action helper not found

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to create a helper of my own. The `Safecheck` folder is located in the `library` folder and contains a `Helper` folder. The class is called `Safecheck_Helper_Authority.php` (inside `library/Safecheck/Helper`).

In `Bootstrap.php`:

```
protected function _initHelper() 
{
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix('Safecheck_Helper');
}
```

In `Safecheck_Helper_Authority.php`:

```
class Safecheck_Helper_Authority extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function hasAuthority($userId, array $ids)
    {

    }
}
```

I want to user the functions inside this class. But I get the error "Message: Action Helper by name Authority not found", triggered by the following code:

```
$this->_helper->authority('hasAuthority');
```

Maybe I am not calling it with the right code? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

in order to call an action helper in this manner `$this->_helper->authority('hasAuthority');` you need to define the [direct()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.writingyourown) method in your helper.

```
class Safecheck_Helper_Authority extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function direct($userId, array $ids)
    {
       // do helper stuff here
    }
}
```

an easy way to register the helper path and prefix is to use the application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.actionhelperpaths.Safecheck_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Safecheck/Helper"
```

to do it in bootstrap (not sure if addPrefix() works with library namespaces):

```
protected function _initHelper() 
{
    //addPath(path_to_helper, helper_prefix)
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath('/../library/Safecheck/Helper', 'Safecheck_Helper');
}
```

a Simple example of an action helper:

```
class Controller_Action_Helper_Login extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    //prepares a login form for display
    public function direct()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_Login();
        $form->setAction('/index/login');

        return $form;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have in your application.ini something similar to

```
resources.frontController.actionhelperpaths.Application_Action_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/../classes/Application/Action/Helper"
```

The path should be changed to reflect your file path.